# How to execute a python script within a virtual environment using the python binary path?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, python-venv

I have a python environment (it could be conda, virtualenv, venv or global python) - I have a python script - hello.py - that I want to execute within that environment.

If I get the path to the python binary within the environment, for example, in windows with a conda environment called myenv, `/path/to/myenv/Scripts/python.exe`,  and if I execute the script using that python, as shown below, am I guaranteed that the script is executed in that environment, independent of the type of virtual environment? If not, what can I do to ensure such a guarantee?

`/path/to/myenv/Scripts/python.exe path/to/hello.py`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right! Furthermore you can evaluate the used executable by using the following snippet:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

Then you will see the absolute path, e.g. `/opt/miniconda/envs/epm/bin/python`.

If you're using a Unix system, you can run:

```
$ echo "import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)" | /opt/miniconda/envs/epm/bin/python
2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
/opt/miniconda/envs/epm/bin/python
```

Comment: If I have multiple environments in different folders, I can simply swap the path to the python executable to have my script run in each environment, right? Nothing else is needed (like activating the environment, changing env variables, etc)?

Comment: Yes, by using an absolute path to a python interpreter the script will be executed explicitly.

Comment: Be careful though, activating conda environments can have side effects (such as changing the PATH variable or other environment variables) that could affect how the script runs. For simple cases, it is sufficient to run the executable explicitly, but there isn't a general solution AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

I suspect not. There are a few environment variables (e.g. `PATH`) which are changed when you activate a virtualenv. You can open up `myenv/bin/activate` in a text editor to see what it does.

Is there a particular reason you want to call the executable directly, rather than use the environment as designed? (e.g. `. ./myenv/bin/activate; python hello.py`)